# (Reference Request) What is this Distribution's name?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $p(x)\triangleq \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{4\pi kx^3}}\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda^2}{4kx}\right)$ supported on $(0,\infty)$, for some $\lambda,k>0$.

Comment: Why doesn't the variable $t$ appear on the right hand side of your formula?  And what is $x$?  And what is $\lambda$?

Comment: Compare to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_inverse_chi-squared_distribution

Comment: Looks an awful lot like the heat kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing but the density of $\frac c {X^{2}}$ where $X$ has standard normal distribution and $ c=\frac {\lambda^{2}} {2k}$. As far as I know there is no name for this.

Comment: Does this admit a nice MGF?

Comment: @MGF I doubt that.